# Values of derivatives of Jacobi theta function

Tags: riemann-zeta, theta-functions

The Jacobi theta function is defined as:

$$\theta(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-\pi n^2 x)\text{   }, x>0$$

On wikipedia.org, we can find close-form expressions for the values of $\theta(k)$,$k=1,2,3,\cdots$.

I am looking for similar formulas for the values of $\frac{d\theta}{d x}(k)$ and $\frac{d^2\theta}{d x^2}(k)$, $k=1,2,3,\cdots$.

This problem showed up when I was looking for approximations to Riemann $\Xi(z)$ function.

Thanks-
mike

Comment: Have you already tried to have a look at Whittaker and Watson's grimoire? It contains many relations involving the theta's and derivatives. I would also try to use the theta functional equation to relate the derivative to the original theta at the integers.Unfortunately, this is all for the time being :-/ ps: nice question!

Comment: @Avitus. Thanks a lot! I will take a look at your valuable suggestions.